# Squid Proxy - Header Spoofing

Tags: squid

I am currently trying to spoof my headers using squid proxy. I have succeeded on insecure websites: http://www.procato.com/my+headers/.

I have not succeeded in secure websites:
https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending

This squid binary was built with --enable-http-violations enabled.
Could someone let me know what I am not doing correctly in my squidfile.conf? Or, alternatively, if there are more steps to spoofing headers on https requests.

```
acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255  # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8             # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10          # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16         # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12          # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16         # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src fc00::/7               # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10              # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling ht
#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# This default configuration only allows localhost requests because a more
# permissive Squid installation could introduce new attack vectors into the
# network by proxying external TCP connections to unprotected services.
http_access allow localhost

# The two deny rules below are unnecessary in this default configuration
# because they are followed by a "deny all" rule. However, they may become
# critically important when you start allowing external requests below them.

# Protect web applications running on the same server as Squid. They often
# assume that only local users can access them at "localhost" ports.
http_access deny to_localhost

# Protect cloud servers that provide local users with sensitive info about
# their server via certain well-known link-local (a.k.a. APIPA) addresses.
http_access deny to_linklocal

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# For example, to allow access from your local networks, you may uncomment the
# following rule (and/or add rules that match your definition of "local"):
# http_access allow localnet

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access allow all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/cache/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/cache/squid

#
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
#
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320

request_header_access User-Agent deny all
request_header_replace User-Agent Nutscrape/1.0
connect_timeout 1 minute
```

Best,

Answer (score 0):

Spoofing an external ip is a lot more complicated than masking the outgoing request. Long story short, this is not really possible.